# Ideas how to solve this (active menu class) with JS/jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have a small problem with my code. I’m adding active class to my menu items. That’s all working fine except one thing. I have a URL like this:

URL: car/some1

URL: truck/some1

And when I click on one URL, both URLS being active (have class active).

HTML:

```
<ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
    <li><a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle " data-toggle="dropdown" data-hover="dropdown" data-close-others="true">Some <i class="fa fa-caret-down" aria-hidden="true"></i></a>
      <ul class="dropdown-menu">
        <li><a href="car/some1">Some 1</a></li>
        <li><a href="">Some 2</a></li>
        <li><a href="">Some 3</a></li>
        <li><a href="">Some 4</a></li>
      </ul>
   </li>
 <li><a href="">News</a></li>
 <li><a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle " data-toggle="dropdown" data-hover="dropdown" data-close-others="true">Some completly new<i class="fa fa-caret-down" aria-hidden="true"></i></a>
   <ul class="dropdown-menu">
      <li><a href="truck/some1">Some 1</a></li>

   </ul>
 </li>

</ul>
```

JS

```
$(document).ready(function () {
   $(".nav li a").click(function(){
     var id = $(this);
     $(".nav li a").removeClass("active");
     $(id).addClass("active");
     sessionStorage .setItem("linkActive", $(id).text());
   }); 
    var linkActive = sessionStorage .getItem('linkActive');
      if (linkActive !== null) {
       $("li a:contains('" + linkActive + "')").addClass("active");
       $("li a:contains('" + linkActive + 
    "')").parents().addClass("active");
    }
});
```

Can anybody help me with this? I have no idea how to solve this.

Comment: I'm not able to reproduce the problem you describe, When I click on `car/some1` only this one is active.

Answer (score 0):

You are storing the text value which is duplicated(*Some 1*) and hence both are selected. Instead, try setting a unique value like the `href`. More on [attr-selector](https://www.w3schools.com/jquery/sel_attribute_contains_string_value.asp)

setting href

```
sessionStorage.setItem("linkActive", $(id).attr('href'));
```

then set via

```
var linkActive = sessionStorage.getItem('linkActive');
$(`li a[href*='${linkActive}']`).addClass("active");
```

**DEMO**

```js
var currentHref;
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("li span").click(function() {
    var id = $(this);
    currentHref = $(id).attr('href');
    console.log(currentHref);
    makeActive();
  });
});

function makeActive() {
  $(`li span[href*='${currentHref}']`).addClass("active");
}
```

```css
.active {
  color: red;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.4.1.min.js" integrity="sha256-CSXorXvZcTkaix6Yvo6HppcZGetbYMGWSFlBw8HfCJo=" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

<ul>
  <li> <span href="jobs">Jobs </span></li>
  <li> <span href="Cars"> Cars </span></li>
  <li> <span href="Flower">Flower </span></li>
</ul>
```

Comment: thank you, now active class are lost, menu items right now doesn't have active class.

Comment: @MihicaStok check the demo, have edited the code. Thanks!

Comment: here is codepen link: https://codepen.io/anon/pen/jgYeNQ still not working

Comment: it's hard to recreate as clicking links will navigate to another page.

Answer (score 0):

Make a separate function and call it on click of the link. The `$(nav li a)` will select any link inside an li

```js
function a(e)
{
 alert("heyy") 
     $(e).removeClass("active");
     $(e).addClass("active");
     sessionStorage .setItem("linkActive", $(id).text());

}
$(document).ready(function () {
    var linkActive = sessionStorage .getItem('linkActive');
      if (linkActive !== null) {
       $("li a:contains('" + linkActive + "')").addClass("active");
       $("li a:contains('" + linkActive + 
    "')").parents().addClass("active");
    }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
    <li><a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle " data-toggle="dropdown" data-hover="dropdown" data-close-others="true">Some <i class="fa fa-caret-down" aria-hidden="true"></i></a>
      <ul class="dropdown-menu">
        <li><a href="car/some1" onclick="a(this)">Some 1</a></li>
        <li><a href="">Some 2</a></li>
        <li><a href="">Some 3</a></li>
        <li><a href="">Some 4</a></li>
      </ul>
   </li>
 <li><a href="">News</a></li>
 <li><a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle " data-toggle="dropdown" data-hover="dropdown" data-close-others="true">Some completly new<i class="fa fa-caret-down" aria-hidden="true"></i></a>
   <ul class="dropdown-menu">
      <li><a href="truck/some1" onclick="a(this)">Some 1</a></li>

   </ul>
 </li>

</ul>
```

Answer (score 0):

**Here URL not issue what ever we use. we just add class and remove class.**

```
$('.dropdown-menu li').on('click', function(){
  $('.dropdown-menu li').removeClass('active');
  $(this).addClass('active');
});
```

Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/bvf9u/

Answer (score 0):

I solve this problem like this:

```
$(function () {
   setNavigation();
});

function setNavigation() {
   var path = window.location.pathname;
   path = path.replace(/\/$/, "");
   path = decodeURIComponent(path);

   $(".nav li a").each(function () {
    var href = $(this).attr('href');
    if (path.substring(0, href.length) === href) {
        $(this).closest('li').addClass('active');
        $(this).closest('li').parents().addClass("active");
      }
    });
}
```